# Does anyone have a working review link for iOS9?

Tags: ios, app-store

Hi I just noticed the link I use in my app that takes the user to my apps review page (which I've been using since iOS7) no longer works:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=<appid>
```

Does anyone have a fix for this? (Note: I know you can use `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id<appid>` but it doesn't take you to the review tab, only to the apps page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In doing some experimenting, I figured out that Apple reverted it back to how it was before iOS7. So you have to do:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=247423477&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software
```

Where `247423477` is your 9 digit app ID (the main difference is you have to append `&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software` after the app ID).

Note: this works on iOS9.0.2 so I'm going to assume it works for all of iOS9. Can anyone check and see if it works on iOS8 and iOS7?

Comment: @iosCurator It still works for me on iOS9.3.2. What is happening for you? Is it possible you entered in the wrong app ID?

Comment: works for me now. Thanks Ser, I entered the wrong id.

Comment: @iosCurator No prob :) Care to remove down vote if that was you?